# How to read Ints as array and output MinMax

Tags: java, arrays, loops, max, min

Currently trying to output the Min and Max of 25 numbers inputed from keyboard, although I am having trouble in the Scanner class to be able to input said numbers. I keep getting an error for cannot make Int[] to an Int.

Here is the question:

> (MinMax.java) Read in 25 ints from the keyboard, and store them in an
>   array.  Find the maximum and minimum values in the array, and display
>   them on the screen.

Here is my current Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MinMax{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter 25 numbers.");
        int[] numbers = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Minimum Value = " + getMinValue(numbers));
        System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + getMaxValue(numbers));  
    }

    public static int getMaxValue(int[] numbers) {
        int maxValue = numbers[0];
        for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i] > maxValue){
                maxValue = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    //Find minimum (lowest) value in array using loop
    public static int getMinValue(int[] numbers){
        int minValue = numbers[0];
        for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i] < minValue){
                minValue = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be because you have written `int[] numbers = sc.nextInt();` You have declared `numbers` as an array of `int`, while `nextInt()` returns a single `int`. Hence your assignment contains incompatible types. You'll need to read numbers in one-by-one and add them into the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
int[] numbers = sc.nextInt();
```

That's because `sc.nextInt()` returns an `int` not an array of `int`s.

Instead, you need to create a loop that reads the 25 integers:

```
int[] numbers = new int[25];
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your main funtion.
Just do this:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 25 numbers.");
    int[] numbers = new int[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        System.out.print("Number " + (i+1) + ": ");
        numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Minimum Value = " + getMinValue(numbers));
    System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + getMaxValue(numbers));
}
```